# From where we get the observed cloud liquid water content data

Tags: clouds

I want to study the clouds and its profile which requires some basic observed variables, does anyone knows how and from where we can get the observed liquid water content data.

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the actual data, or do you want to know how it's observed and collected?

Comment: I want to know that, from which website we can get the observed data